# Facebook API: find out whether private message links into business manager or not

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When fetching page conversations, I receive a `link` field. This link field is an absolute path, without the server, e.g. `/PAGE-12312/manager/messages/?mercurythreadid=....`

Depending on whether a page is managed via the "Facebook Business Manager" or not, that link should be either opened via `facebook.com` or `business.facebook.com`.

How can I find out whether the FB page is managed via the business manager, i.e. how can I know how to properly construct the link back to facebook?

Linking to a private messages on a page managed via the business manager does not word, i.e. opening `facebook.com/PAGE-12312/manager/messages/?mercurythreadid=....` leads to an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `business` field on the `/{page-id}` node in graph api is the ID of the business that owns the page in Business Manager, if any. It's only available with a page admin token.

You have to ask explicitly for the field in the api-request:

```
/{page-id}/?fields=business
```

Answer (score 0):

The way we <s>solved</s> worked this around is by realizing that you can *always* link into the Business Manager, even when the page doesn't have it activated.